# Amazon ECS, capacity provider not able to provide required capacity

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

I want to create an ECS cluster with two capacity providers:

- standard that uses on-demand instances
- spot, that uses spot instances

ECS is going to be linked to auto-scaling groups and handle scaling for the above providers.

When defining a service, I am going to use custom capacity provider strategy. The sample configuration could be as follow:

- base: 2 for the standard provider
- weight: 0 for the standard provider, 1 for the spot provider

If I am not mistaken, with that configuration, my service should create 2 instances on the standard (on-demand) provider, and rest on the spot one.

Assuming I want to manage 10 tasks under my service. 

In the happy path, 2 of them runs on my standard provider, and 8 on the spot.

Here is the question - how is the unhappy scenario handled when spot instances are not available? 
Will my service contains only 2 tasks that were placed on the on-demand instances?

If yes, how can I dynamically adjust my service to temporarily use only the on-demand provider?

Or, maybe the above configuration doesn't make any sense, and there is a better way to utilize spot instance and ECS to cut costs?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Capacity Providers and services combination do not think about if the instances they are running on are spot or on-demand https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/773

Your configuration seems reasonable for using spot. Assuming that you pick a range of instance type and availability zone then there is typically sufficient spot capacity. However, Amazoan always states that you shouldn't run production workloads on spot :shrug:

Comment: Cheers for the response. I added my there and hopefully, Amazon will listen ;)